# Angular 4 and Bootstrap 4 navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, navbar

I have a problem with Angular 4 and Bootstrap 4. The default navbar I got from the example looks not how it's supposed to be:

[image: navbar in the app]

It's the other way around and the navbar opens on the right side, like in a small view.

I´ve installed Bootstrap 4 over the angular-cli. Also everything should be up to date.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it.. I was using the alpha doc..

Comment: I faced the same problem, after changing the bootstrap version from 4.0.0 to "bootstrap": "^3.3.7" it worked for me.

Comment: If possible always post your code which you have tried.